# How do I close await <coroutine> in IPython?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, python-asyncio

I am trying to learn asyncio. I have this coroutine:
`co_get_json = <coroutine object Client.get_json at 0x7fcd5dff9d40>`

It has a corresponding non-async version `get_json`.

I then typed `await co_r` in IPython. Now anytime I run `get_json` (the non async version) I get the error `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`.

How do I close the event loop?
`>>>asyncio.get_event_loop()`
`<_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>`.

If I type `asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()`, my IPython kernel dies. I've tried restarting to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the [IPython docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/autoawait.html), I finally fixed it by installing `nest-asyncio` and running `nest_asyncio.apply()`. Hopefully this will help future users!